# Iterating through all Combinations of Features by Selection in ArcGIS Python Script

Tags: arcpy, select

I have a question about ArcGIS and a Python script.
There are following sample code,
So I would like to change Another Field , not OIDFieldName.
Please let me know how to change Another Field.

```
import arcpy
import itertools

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\path\to\workspace"

base_shapefile = "some_shapefile.shp"

oid_field = arcpy.Describe(base_shapefile).OIDFieldName
feature_count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(base_shapefile).getOutput(0))

for (i, j) in itertools.combinations(range(feature_count), 2):
    arcpy.Select_analysis(base_shapefile , "combination_%i_%i.shp" % (i, j), '"%s" in (%i, %i)' % (oid_field, i, j))
```

These sample code is combination for 5C2. I want to create all combinations 5C3 , 5C4 , 5C5.

Comment: If you use SelectLayerByAttribute instead of Select_Analysis, you can append to your selection each iteration. Please try "ADD_TO_SELECTION" as the second parameter.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I'm thinking there isn't actually a field called "Another Field". I'm not seeing where "5C3" and the like are coming from; are these other fields? Also, I'm not seeing you actually changing field values with the `Select`. Can you edit your question for clarity?

Comment: 5C2, 5C3, etc. are the OP's shorthand for [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) (i.e. the number of possible unique outcomes from choosing 2, 3, etc. items out of 5 total).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `fields` instead of `OIDFieldName` which will return a Python list of Field objects for this table. This is the same as using the ListFields function.

```
field_list = arcpy.Describe(base_shapefile).fields
for field in field_list:
    print field.basename
```

Then you can specify what field will be used as input for the code that performs business logic later; this can be either a string representing field.basename or a geoprocessing field object (depending on the need).

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of Another Field, you can simply specify it as a string. So instead of `oid_field = arcpy.Describe(base_shapefile).OIDFieldName`, you would just use `field_name = "ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME"` (and replace subsequent references to `oid_field` with `field_name`).

To answer your other question, you can get a list of all values of "ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME" and set up a loop to perform the multiple levels of combinations. The full code would be something like this:

```
import arcpy
import itertools

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\path\to\workspace"

base_shapefile = "some_shapefile.shp"

field_name = "ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME"
field_values = list(set([str(row[0]) for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(base_shapefile, [field_name])]))
field_values.sort()  # Put values in a nice order for combinations

for n in range(3, 6):  #=> [3, 4, 5]
    for combo in itertools.combinations(field_values, n):
        value_str_1 = "_".join(combo)
        out_shp = "combination_" + value_str_1 + ".shp"

        # If field is not TEXT, remove single-quotes from these:
        value_str_2 = "', '".join(combo)
        query_str = """ "{0}" IN ('{1}') """.format(field_name, value_str_2)

        arcpy.Select_analysis(base_shapefile, out_shp, query_str)
```