# ArcGIS python itertools.combinations

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop

There is following sample code combination 5C2.  I want to create all combinations 5C1 , 5C3 , 5C4 and 5C5.

```
list = [ 0,1,2,3,4 ]
5C1 means (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
5C2 means (0,1),(0,2),(0,3),..(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)..,(2,3),(2,4)
5C3 means (0,1,2),(0,1,3),(0,1,4),(0,1,5)..(1,2,3),(1,2,4)
5C4 means (0,1,2,3),(0,1,2,4),(0,1,2,5)..(1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,5)
5C5 means (0,1,2,3,4)
```

Please let me know your advice and comments.

```
import arcpy
import itertools

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\path\to\workspace"

base_shapefile = "some_shapefile.shp"

oid_field = arcpy.Describe(base_shapefile).OIDFieldName
feature_count = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(base_shapefile).getOutput(0))

for (i, j) in itertools.combinations(range(feature_count), 2):
    arcpy.Select_analysis(base_shapefile , "combination_%i_%i.shp" % (i, j), '"%s" in (%i, %i)' % (oid_field, i, j))
```

Comment: Your question is very vague, please give additional background info. of what you are trying to do.

Comment: ...for example what the combinations of 5CX means.

Comment: Yes, I want to do 5CX

Comment: 5CX?? This still makes no sense.

Comment: @Chad Although I agree the question is vague and desperately needs to be clarified, at least the meaning of "nCk" can be gleaned from the (rather erroneous!) examples at the beginning: these are supposed to be all combinations of *n* things taken *k* at a time. Whence, taking *n* = 5, the list must have *five* elements and we can take it to be `[0,1,2,3,4]` (in a particular, 5 does not appear in it). Thus "5C1" would consist of the lists `[0]`, `[1]`, ..., `[4]`; "5C2" would consist of `[0,1]`, `[0,2]`, `[0,3]`, `[0,4]`, `[1,2]`, `[1,3]`, `[1,4]`, `[2,3]`, `[2,4]`, and `[3,4]`, and so on.

Comment: I answered this question in the OP's [other question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83977/iterate-through-all-combinations-of-features-by-selection-in-arcgis-python-scrip) (where it was originally posed in a comment).

Comment: Although OP is using arcpy, this is a pure python question relating to the use of the itertools package so probably belongs on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do, you want one new feature class per OID. I think that it would be more simple to take advantage of the string concatenation in Python. the first parameter of select analysis is your input, the second will be "combination5C1_0.shp, combination5C1_1.shp, ..., combination5C2_2.shp ..., the third will be, e.g., "FID" in (0,1) (with shapefile, FID is the default oid fiel name).

```
for i in (range(feature_count) +1):
    counter =0
    for x in itertools.combinations(range(feature_count), i):
        counter += 1
        arcpy.Select_analysis(base_shapefile , "combination5C" + str(i) + "_" + str(counter) +  ".shp",'"' + oid_field + '" in ' + str(x))
```

I use a counter here, because you cannot create more than one shp with the same name, and using the first value of your combination, as you did, may yield the same output name.

Note that with some geodatabase, the where clause should put the field names between [ ] and not between " "

Also, it is often not a good idea to make a large number of small shapefiles. You could use layers instead.

```
   arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(base_shapefile , "combination5C" + str(i) + "_" + str(counter) ,'"' + oid_field + '" in ' + str(x))
```

Comment: Can you give a little context what your code snippet is doing for the non programmers?

Comment: I could create only 5C1 as you reply.

Comment: sorry, I had not seen the updated question.

Comment: I am lerning python script.

Comment: So here is my updated answer.